# China - Binhai - Aircraft Carrier Amusement park - Hands on or just looking only?

Tags: china, activities, sport

I have heard about an Amusement Park in Binhai (near Tianjin, I think) where one can visit a decommissioned aircraft carrier. In it are soviet era keepsakes and a whole assortment of military memorabilia -- which is definitely cool, but I'm not sure I'd personally go all the way there if it's just a museum-like deal (looking only).

### Question

Can anyone with experience in the region share what the more hands-on activities are?

I'd personally consider it worth it if one can jet-ski around the aircraft carrier, which there appears to be some advertising for. However, I can't rule out those photos were just the staff putting on a jet-ski show for the visitors. If the visitors themselves can't jet ski, I'm afraid it will feel too similar to a museum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** There's nothing hands on.

IIRC, it is not even a museum. If I'm not mistaken, it is the former Soviet aircraft carrier Kiev. Basically, all equipment has been removed from the aircraft carrier before its sale to China, so that China could not convert it and put it in service (of course, late we know this doesn't work).

So basically, there would be nothing to see besides the empty hull. There is a small theme park around where carrier is, but there's nothing hand on (it's just a Russian-themed park with some retired weaponry to see). There are some shows, but definitely nothing hands on; it was most likely a jet-ski show of some sort. Most of the aircraft carrier itself has been converted to a hotel.